# Uncertain about USB-C Power delivery

Tags: power-supply, usb, usb-c

I'm super rudimentary when it comes to elecrical knowledge.

I have a wireless charging transmitter coil that has the following specs:

- Input Current
  1.8Amax. @12.0Vdc Full load
- Inrush Current(cold)
  2.0Amax. @12.0Vdc Full load & Ambient temperature25 °C
- Energy Consumption
  At 11.5VDC or 12.5VDC, Energy Consumption≤ 0.03A

This component has overcurrent protection and is certified by UL and the Wireless Power Consortium.

It has no power input on the board, I need to add one myself. I want to solder bare wires that run to a usb-c female socket to then run power from a standard wall adapter. I want to use usb-c 3.1 because the spec says it can handle that much current (a.k.a. fast charge), but I don't know if I need something further to make that happen.

Three questions:

1) If I buy a breakout board with a USB C 3.1 socket that has no IC's on it, can I safely assume that it will just pass through whatever power is given to it, and will power the board?

2) Should I use a wall adapter that is 5v 3a, or 12v 1.8a? I keep reading that power supplies supply *up to* the amount listed but provide less if the receiving device requires less.

3) What size bare wire should I use between the USB C socket and the board? I have been looking all over for wire size charts but all I can find are for much higher loads. I was thinking I'd need to use between 20 and 24 gauge wire but would love some input.

Thanks for whatever help you guys can provide.

Comment: Don't do this. The USB specification is very strict about how you can wire up USB cables, and putting 12V on a USB cable without the proper power delivery negotiation is a very bad idea.

Comment: So if the board has these input specs, what should I look for in terms of power supply? Just a 12v 1.8a power supply?

Comment: @Hearth Just to be clear, the only thing I want from the USB socket is the socket. The board itself is simply looking for the 12v 1.8a input spec, so my question is will a usb 3.1 female socket just act as a passhtrough from the wall adapter? I don't understand how power negotiation works so any info on where to learn more about that would be helpful. TBH "don't do that" without any explanation about where to go from here is actually pretty unhelpful.

Comment: Could you please be more clear on what do you have? Do you have a "transmitter coil" but without power input? Which device has the "usb-c female socket" then?

Comment: @Ale..chenski
All I have is the transmitter module.
The module is a transmitter coil wired to an IC controller that has solder points for power but no socket of any sort. I want to solder a usb-c socket TO the board to supply power. The end result would be wall adapter -> usb cable -> USB female socket -> bare wire -> controller. Everything from the adapter to the bare wire is what I do not have worked out yet. I just need a way to plug the thing in, and I'm trying to figure out the best interface for that. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can't transmit "12V 1.8A" over wireless coils, the power comes over electromagnetic AC field. These specs must be for the base charger. These specs have nothing to do with internal voltages and currents inside your transmitter module. You need to understand what kind of voltage is coming out of power coil inside your transmitter, and supply the same via physical wires. Or determine the voltage output of the main voltage regulator inside, and bypass it with proper voltage. At this level, I would strongly recommend to forget about Type-C things, and wire the transmitter internals directly.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused. The input requirement is 12v 1.8a, isn't that simply what I want to supply it? It regulates everything internally, afaik. This is to supply power *to the transmitter* not to *transmit the power* (that's the job of the module)

Comment: It is me who is seriously confused. Which input if you say that your device has no power input? Who transmits and what?

Comment: Let me restate. The module requires 2a inrush or 1.8a under standard load, at 12v.
It has GND and VIN solder joints but there is currently nothing connected to them. I want a wire that connects 12 volts at 2 amps to the board. There is presently no way to plug it in until I add a female socket that supplies power. I want that female socket to be in the physical shape of a USB-C port, for vanity reasons only. Otherwise, I don't care that it is USB-C. You could easily swap this out with a 12v barrel jack, but I want the USB-C connectiong because of aesthetics. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Literally, I want the USB-C to just be a pass-through. I want it to act like an extension of a wire from a 12v/2a wall adapter connected straight to the board. So the question becomes, is it stupid to think that I can just use a usb-c female jack, connect it to the power pins on board, and expec it to work normally, or am I being naive?